# When using the Eris API, it is not possible to use the API with my own uploaded shapefile

Tags: javascript

When I was writing the webgis, I used eris' API. The tutorial only taught how to use their own URL. When I used my own uploaded URL, it gave an error. How can I use my own URL?

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript Tutorials: Add a feature layer</title>
  <style>
    html, body, #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.28/esri/themes/light/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.28/"></script>

  <script>
  require([
    "esri/config",
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",

    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer"

  ], function(esriConfig, Map, MapView, FeatureLayer) {

  esriConfig.apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";

  const map = new Map({
    basemap: "arcgis/topographic"
  });

  const view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
    center: [-118.80543,34.02700],
    zoom: 13
  });

//Trailheads feature layer (points)
  const trailheadsLayer = new FeatureLayer({
    url: "https://services3.arcgis.com/GVgbJbqm8hXASVYi/arcgis/rest/services/Trailheads/FeatureServer/0"
  });

  map.add(trailheadsLayer);

//Trails feature layer (lines)
  const trailsLayer = new FeatureLayer({
    url: "https://services3.arcgis.com/GVgbJbqm8hXASVYi/arcgis/rest/services/Trails/FeatureServer/0"
  });

  map.add(trailsLayer, 0);

// Parks and open spaces (polygons)
  const parksLayer = new FeatureLayer({
    url: "https://services3.arcgis.com/qPQQycqtkiAa89x6/arcgis/rest/services/xishan/FeatureServer"
  });

  map.add(parksLayer, 0);

  });
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to change the URL to my own, but it will throw an error saying it cannot find my URL in the FeatureLayer.